# Find dCS/dp. Why do you find the value you do? Interpret it.

Tags: calculus, economics

So I have a demand function:

$$D(p)=A-ap$$

And I've  found $\frac{d}{dp} CS$ which is $-D(p)=-(A-ap)=-A+ap$.

I'm not sure what to conclude, but I've said that "More products sold will result in a rise in prices." I'm concluding this because when i illustrate the $\frac{d}{dp} CS=-D(p)$, it shows just that.

Can anybody please confirm or deny? I'm kinda lost.

Comment: It seems like you probably wanted $\frac{d}{dp} D(p)= \frac{d}{dp} (A - ap) = -a$. Then the interpretation of this is that as prices rise the demand falls

Comment: The statement as written is correct though since CS integrates out demand

Answer (score -1):

If consumers pay a price $p$, consumer surplus is

$$CS(p)=\int_p^\infty D(\tilde p)d\tilde p $$,

which captures the monetary gain afforded to consumers due to the gap between what they are willing to pay and what they actually pay.

So $\partial_p CS(p)=-D(p).$ This tells us roughly that for every unit increase in the price, the CS drops by the amount demanded.

This makes sense since consumers buy less as the price goes up and thus enjoy less welfare.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted; it is correct---comment if you think otherwise